# Samba Share user/password error after update

Tags: networking, server, password, samba

this is the first time that I couldn't find an answer so this is my first question. I will provide as much information as possible. I have an ASUS router that has 2 HDDs. There is only 1 username/password to access the media while on the network. My PC no longer seems to be able to access it after an update.

After initially entering the login credentials and selecting "Remember forever" I had always (over 2 years) been able to access the drives by going to "Browse Network" in nautilus and clicking on the Router's Icon then clicking the folder I want to access. Today I had a security update which contained the following:

[image]

Now when I go to access the folders on the HDDs this pops up:

[image]

I select "Registered User" enter the username, password and select "Remember forever" then click Connect and the box pops back up greyed out with the fields reset to defaults.

If I click the connect button again the same greyed out pop-up keeps coming back over and over.

If I manually close it. A brand new pop-up appears that allows me to enter in the credentials. However, if I enter them again nautilus simply closes and I occassionally get a pop-up saying that Ubuntu has encountered and internal error etc.

There are 3 Phones, 1 Tablet, 1 Win7 PC, and another Ubuntu 15.10 PC that can connect to the network drives and read/write without issue. I should add that I ignored the update mentioned above on the other Ubuntu PC once I started to have this issue on mine.

So far the only way I can access the HDDs with my PC is to turn off my router's security for samba access. I really have no idea how to remedy this or how to get it back to the way it was.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I used to have the same setup as you, and no it doesn't work anymore on 16.04. I spent a lot of time trying to make it work. Those same changes have just, hours ago, been released back to 15.10 and 14.04. In my case I added myself and my password to the samba users stuff (i.e. `sudo smbpasswd -a doug'), whereas I has never had to do that before.

Comment: I just discovered the bad way, about the latest update as well.. still trying to get my samba server to accept windows users again.
Android, Linux, and Apple devices have no problem accessing samba shares only Windows machines are unable to access samba after the latest ubuntu patch for samba.

Comment: Recently there was a serious security flaw detected in the Windows file sharing protocol as included in Windows and implemented by Samba for linux/unix systems.  The recent updates of Windows & Samba contained the fix for that, but it seems like that breaks some setups, both on Windows & on linux…

Comment: There might be more information at https://www.samba.org/samba/latest_news.html#4.4.2

Comment: … and https://www.samba.org/samba/history/samba-4.3.8.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I first added the line `client use spnego = no` at the end of file `/etc/samba/smb.conf`, but it did not work. After I placed the line near the beginning of the file, the network drives worked.

Comment: Cheers. This is what did the trick. I just had to put the line near the top right after the global settings break. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

I had exactly the same problem.
Adding

```
client use spnego = no
```

to the [global] section of `/etc/samba/smb.conf` solved the problem in my case.
Apparently the default value changed to "yes" after the update to v.4.3.8, so I needed to explicitly set it.

See the [online manpage](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html) for reference.

Comment: I added the line of text as your suggested to no avail. The problem still persists. Thank you though.

Comment: @user531897 did you check if there are any other values that changed their default after the update? e.g. "client use spnego" was not set in my smb.conf. This was ok before, as per the previous version the default value was "no". but now they changed it to "yes", so I had to set it manually. Maybe for you there is a similar problem with another option?

Comment: overall you had the right answer it apparently just had to be at the very top of the file (as stated by user18778) right after the global settings break... After a reboot everything works as it did before. Thank you.

Comment: as @xenog remarked (in an edit, that should have been a comment): If you do not have the `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file, install package `samba-common` (`sudo apt install samba-common`). This was necessary for him/her on a fresh installation of Ubuntu Gnome 16.04.

Answer (score 1):

I tried use smbclient to see what happened I got this:

> SMB server does not support EXTENDED_SECURITY  but 'client use spnego = yes and 'client ntlmv2 auth = yes'

I think this means samba client is telling the samba server use features which are not there. From use Samba's note above with [this link](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html) I found this:

> The impact of '`client ntlmv2 auth = yes`' is that by default we will not use NTLM (NT Local Machine) authentication as a client.

Since I am not using any extended security I just turn this off as
"`client ntlmv2 auth = no`" in `/etc/samba/smb.conf`. I have to added a line to override the default. Everything is working again.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please don't add "thanks" as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](//askubuntu.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, which is the Ask Ubuntu way of saying thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have winbind installed. Install it if haven´t got it and restart samba-ad-dc again. You should be fine after that.

https://lists.samba.org/archive/samba/2016-April/199291.html

Comment: I installed winbind. Restarted samba. Rebooted just in case. Still no change. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes after the latest update I did yestarday samba was not able to connect as a client via the nautilus.
Mounting via the mount direct command still was working.
I had to change the smb.conf file as suggested above by adding

client use spnego = no

Then you have to restart the samba network stack (just reboot).

Everything is working now.