# Simple Samba setup kicking my butt

Tags: permissions, samba, file-sharing, nas, smb

Samba in standalone mode, just one share. Windows client says "You do not have permission". Using UNIX ACL's, have a simple one line mapping file for a single user. Using tdb as back end, have enabled and configured a UNIX user and a smbpasswd password for said user. smb.conf:

```
[global]
    server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
    server role = standalone server
    pam password change = Yes
    passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
    passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
    unix password sync = Yes
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    max log size = 1000
    panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
    idmap config * : backend = tdb
    username map = /etc/samba/usermaps

[nas-share]
    comment = NAS Share
    path = /raid/nas-share
    read only = No
    guest ok = Yes
```

server-side folder perms:

```
drwxrwsr-x  2 root smb-write  4096 Nov 10 16:21 nas-share
```

user mapping file:

```
test = Test
```

UNIX user is a part of the "smb-write" group, but share is also configured to allow for guest access (read/execute). At a loss, Samba will not let a Windows client to connect no matter what I try, any ideas? Have I missed a critical step? Any and all help greatly appreciated. Will post any config I missed if needed.

Comment: You could turn to the Samba troubleshooting checklist. A quick trick borrowed from that document for testing your Samba configuration file for obvious errors is to run the following command:

 `testparm smb.conf`

After that, is it the connection from Windows to Ubuntu that is causing the issue, or the other way around ?

Comment: @Piloti Windows to Ubuntu is the issue, Ubuntu is the server, Windows is the Client. Link to checklist? I have already run testparm and it came up clean (or claimed to).

Comment: I'm not sure this will help, but I found this

`https://askubuntu.com/questions/763945/cant-connect-to-smb-share-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-gnome-16-04`

Comment: More info: If I add my test user to the share with the admin users flag it lets me in.....   why?!?! Code:

      `admin users = test`

Comment: Can you delete the line `username map =` and retry? As far as I know, Samba will automatically lowercase usernames received from Windows.

Comment: Check your `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file, and ensure there is a line in the global section "encrypt passwords = true " - if you have to add the line, then you also need to `sudo service smbd restart`