# Can't connect to Samba shared folders

Tags: 16.04, samba

Using Ubuntu 16.04 and `samba` version `2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.1`.

I have shared a folder using Nautilus, but I can't connect to it either though Nautilus or through `smbclient`.
Nautilus repeatedly asks for authentication, while `smbclient` returns:

```
tree connect failed: NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED
```

I tried adding `client use spnego = no` to `/etc/samba/smb.conf` as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/758860/samba-share-user-password-error-after-update/763436), but this only changes the error to:

```
session setup failed: NT_STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER
```

If I allow guest access to the folder, everything works correctly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer.

Samba doesn't use the normal Ubuntu user credentials for authentication.
It uses its own credentials database.

---

To add a user to the Samba credentials database, execute:

```
sudo smbpasswd -a USERNAME
```

Where `USERNAME` is your Ubuntu username.
Then, after entering the `sudo` password, enter your Ubuntu password twice.
Do this for every user, then Samba will work.

---

This can also be done graphically by installing and using `system-config-samba`.

However `system-config-samba` doesn't start because the file `/etc/libuser.conf` is missing.
You need to create it first (an empty file will do):

```
sudo touch /etc/libuser.conf
```

---

Canonical and Ubuntu Developers: **this is not user friendly!**

Comment: For the `system-config-samba` bug, I sent a patch here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/system-config-samba/+bug/1387274