# Ubuntu 18.04 Cannot connect to Windows shared network folder

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, samba, ntfs

I've been attempted to hook up some kind of shared folder between my Ubuntu VM and Windows 7 Host, Guest Additions Shared Folder is absolute garbage, constantly having file in use issues / text file busy that I cannot resolve for the life of me.

I've now been attempting to setup a host-only network between Ubuntu and Windows (which appears to work fine, both can ping each other's IP), but I appear to have hit a snag where I'm unable to see or modify the network shared windows folder. When using smb://IP/vm_share (vm_share being the name of the folder that is shared in windows), it does not error saying that the folder does not exist, but instead greys everything out (so I can no longer edit the user or password) and only allows me to spam click Connect (which does nothing).

Does anyone have any suggestions? Windows File Sharing is enabled in networking.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Does this help https://askubuntu.com/questions/758860/samba-share-user-password-error-after-update

Comment: Post "sudo apt install samba" I see even more variations of my device in Other Locations, but modifying smb.conf has not yielded any results.